# How to deploy a deep learning model in a windows 32bit machine?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, pytorch

I have trained a crnn model for ocr with tensorflow. Then I deployed it with tensorflow c++ API on a windows 64 bit machine and it works well.
Now I want to deploy the model on a windows 32 bit machine , but I notice that most most deep learning frameworks like tensorflow and pytorch don't support 32 bit machine.
Then I tried opencv dnn module and ncnn framework, but they both don't support the squeeze and unsqueeze operation which are used in my model.
Now I have no idea, could any one give me some suggestions? 
Thanks.

Comment: Depending how complicated your model is, it may be able to export it as an ONNX model and then run it using Microsoft's ONNX runtime, which can be built for 32bit: https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime/blob/master/BUILD.md

Comment: Thank you, I notice that the onnx doesn't support the dynaimc input. But my input image has a dynamic width, like (1,3,32,-1) in tensorflow,.

Answer (score 0):

The closest to your problem might be this
https://github.com/VisionRush/Caffe-Win32

This is with caffe on Windows 32 bit.

P/S: That is a CPU only build. For GPU support, you will have to tweak the caffe source code there a bit, something like `CpuToCpu` to `CpuToGpu`. However, you won't be able to use cuDNN with 32 bit caffe.